# Libvirt Ubuntu Installation HVM Issue

Tags: ubuntu, qemu, kvm, libvirt, virsh

So I've been trying to spin up an Ubuntu server install using virt-install, and I can't seem to get it to work. It fails out with the following message:

```
ERROR    Couldn't find hvm kernel for Ubuntu tree.
```

I've seen forum posts all over about this issue, but all of those seem to say the issue was fixed with version 1.5.1, which I'm currently using:

```
$ virt-install --version 
1.5.1
```

I've included the output while using --debug below:

```
    $ virt-install --name u001 --ram 2048 --disk path=/srv/virt/ubuntu_u001.img,size=20 --hvm --debug --vcpus 2 --os-type linux --os-variant ubuntu18.04 --network bridge=virt0 --graphics none --console pty,target_type=serial --location '/mnt/ubu' --extra-args 'console=ttyS0,115200n8 serial'
[Wed, 26 Sep 2018 04:18:25 virt-install 22043] DEBUG (cli:265) Launched with command line: /usr/share/virt-manager/virt-install --name u001 --ram 2048 --disk path=/srv/virt/ubuntu_u001.img,size=20 --hvm --debug --vcpus 2 --os-type linux --os-variant ubuntu18.04 --network bridge=virt0 --graphics none --console pty,target_type=serial --location /mnt/ubu --extra-args console=ttyS0,115200n8 serial
[Wed, 26 Sep 2018 04:18:25 virt-install 22043] DEBUG (cli:279) Requesting libvirt URI default
[Wed, 26 Sep 2018 04:18:25 virt-install 22043] DEBUG (cli:282) Received libvirt URI qemu:///system
[Wed, 26 Sep 2018 04:18:25 virt-install 22043] DEBUG (virt-install:358) Requesting virt method 'hvm', hv type 'default'.
[Wed, 26 Sep 2018 04:18:25 virt-install 22043] DEBUG (virt-install:583) Received virt method 'kvm'
[Wed, 26 Sep 2018 04:18:25 virt-install 22043] DEBUG (virt-install:584) Hypervisor name is 'hvm'
[Wed, 26 Sep 2018 04:18:25 virt-install 22043] DEBUG (virt-install:270) Distilled --network options: ['bridge=virt0']
[Wed, 26 Sep 2018 04:18:25 virt-install 22043] DEBUG (virt-install:183) Distilled --disk options: ['path=/srv/virt/ubuntu_u001.img,size=20']
[Wed, 26 Sep 2018 04:18:25 virt-install 22043] DEBUG (devicedisk:409) Creating volume 'ubuntu_u001.img' on pool 'virt'
[Wed, 26 Sep 2018 04:18:25 virt-install 22043] DEBUG (devicedisk:535) disk.set_vol_install: name=ubuntu_u001.img poolxml=
<pool type='dir'>
  <name>virt</name>
  <uuid>b91e3a3d-ca07-43f9-bbc2-866e6ded1bde</uuid>
  <capacity unit='bytes'>379406721024</capacity>
  <allocation unit='bytes'>100485763072</allocation>
  <available unit='bytes'>278920957952</available>
  <source>
  </source>
  <target>
    <path>/srv/virt</path>
    <permissions>
      <mode>0755</mode>
      <owner>1000</owner>
      <group>1000</group>
    </permissions>
  </target>
</pool>

[Wed, 26 Sep 2018 04:18:25 virt-install 22043] DEBUG (distroinstaller:180) DistroInstaller location is a network source.
[Wed, 26 Sep 2018 04:18:25 virt-install 22043] DEBUG (guest:251) Setting Guest.os_variant to 'ubuntu18.04'
[Wed, 26 Sep 2018 04:18:25 virt-install 22043] DEBUG (urlfetcher:56) Using scratchdir=/var/lib/libvirt/boot
[Wed, 26 Sep 2018 04:18:25 virt-install 22043] DEBUG (urlfetcher:503) Finding distro store for location=/mnt/ubu
[Wed, 26 Sep 2018 04:18:25 virt-install 22043] DEBUG (urlfetcher:522) variant=ubuntu18.04 has distro=ubuntu, looking for matching distro store to prioritize
[Wed, 26 Sep 2018 04:18:25 virt-install 22043] DEBUG (urlfetcher:529) Prioritizing distro store=<class 'virtinst.urlfetcher.UbuntuDistro'>
[Wed, 26 Sep 2018 04:18:25 virt-install 22043] DEBUG (urlfetcher:1144) No treearch found in uri, defaulting to arch=i386
[Wed, 26 Sep 2018 04:18:25 virt-install 22043] DEBUG (urlfetcher:144) hasFile(/mnt/ubu/current/images/MANIFEST) returning False
[Wed, 26 Sep 2018 04:18:25 virt-install 22043] DEBUG (urlfetcher:144) hasFile(/mnt/ubu/daily/MANIFEST) returning False
[Wed, 26 Sep 2018 04:18:25 virt-install 22043] DEBUG (urlfetcher:144) hasFile(/mnt/ubu/.disk/info) returning True
[Wed, 26 Sep 2018 04:18:25 virt-install 22043] DEBUG (urlfetcher:89) Fetching URI: /mnt/ubu/.disk/info
[Wed, 26 Sep 2018 04:18:25 virt-install 22043] DEBUG (urlfetcher:543) Detected distro name=Ubuntu osvariant=None
[Wed, 26 Sep 2018 04:18:25 virt-install 22043] DEBUG (virt-install:697) Guest.has_install_phase: True

Starting install...
[Wed, 26 Sep 2018 04:18:25 virt-install 22043] DEBUG (urlfetcher:144) hasFile(/mnt/ubu/install/vmlinuz) returning False
[Wed, 26 Sep 2018 04:18:25 virt-install 22043] DEBUG (cli:317)   File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virt-install", line 1008, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virt-install", line 1002, in main
    start_install(guest, options)
  File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virt-install", line 728, in start_install
    fail(e, do_exit=False)
  File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtinst/cli.py", line 317, in fail
    logging.debug("".join(traceback.format_stack()))

[Wed, 26 Sep 2018 04:18:25 virt-install 22043] ERROR (cli:318) Couldn't find hvm kernel for Ubuntu tree.
[Wed, 26 Sep 2018 04:18:25 virt-install 22043] DEBUG (cli:320) 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virt-install", line 707, in start_install
    transient=options.transient)
  File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtinst/guest.py", line 480, in start_install
    self._prepare_install(meter, dry)
  File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtinst/guest.py", line 313, in _prepare_install
    self.installer.prepare(self, meter)
  File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtinst/installer.py", line 200, in prepare
    self._prepare(guest, meter)
  File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtinst/distroinstaller.py", line 220, in _prepare
    self._prepare_kernel_url(guest, fetcher)
  File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtinst/distroinstaller.py", line 128, in _prepare_kernel_url
    kernel, initrd, args = store.acquireKernel(guest)
  File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtinst/urlfetcher.py", line 622, in acquireKernel
    {"distro": self.name, "type": self.type})
RuntimeError: Couldn't find hvm kernel for Ubuntu tree.
[Wed, 26 Sep 2018 04:18:25 virt-install 22043] DEBUG (cli:331) Domain installation does not appear to have been successful.
If it was, you can restart your domain by running:
  virsh --connect qemu:///system start u001
otherwise, please restart your installation.
Domain installation does not appear to have been successful.
If it was, you can restart your domain by running:
  virsh --connect qemu:///system start u001
otherwise, please restart your installation.
```

For reference, the host machine is running Arch. Any ideas?

Comment: What is in the directory `/mnt/ubu`?

Comment: A mounted Ubuntu server 18.04.1 iso

Comment: Questions about **general computing hardware and software** are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming. You may be able to get help on [su].

Answer (score 1):

I had similar problem. Try to use other iso image. I replaced ubuntu-18.04.1-live-server-amd64.iso to ubuntu-18.04.1-server-amd64.iso (you can download it from this site: http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/releases/18.04/release/ ) and everrything goes forward ok.